# I downloaded the eclipse ADT bundle and unzipped it.But later when i tried to open it, the program crashes everytime. Here's my bug report. Plz help

Tags: eclipse, adt

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fea00c91718, pid=18962, tid=140643227506432
JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_72-b14) (build 1.7.0_72-b14)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.72-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
C  [libgobject-2.0.so.0+0x19718]  g_object_get_qdata+0x18

Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
See problematic frame for where to report the bug.


---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007fea0400a800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=18963, stack(0x00007fea0d8d9000,0x00007fea0d9da000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000000000003e00

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000003e00, RBX=0x00007fea0479fbb0, RCX=0x0000000000000375, RDX=0x00007fea0479fbb0
RSP=0x00007fea0d9d6a10, RBP=0x0000000000000375, RSI=0x0000000000000375, RDI=0x00007fea0479fbb0
R8 =0x00000000ffffffff, R9 =0x0000000000005300, R10=0x00007fea01012d6c, R11=0x00007fea0c821b80
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x00000000b113c588, R14=0x00007fea0d9d6ac8, R15=0x00007fea0400a800
RIP=0x00007fea00c91718, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007fea0d9d6a10)
0x00007fea0d9d6a10:   00007fea01005310 00000000b113c588
0x00007fea0d9d6a20:   00007fea0d9d6a98 00007fe9a75af0e3
0x00007fea0d9d6a30:   00000000f4123170 00007fea01012d98
0x00007fea0d9d6a40:   0000000000000001 00000000eadf1cf0
0x00007fea0d9d6a50:   0000000000000001 00007fea0d9d6a58
0x00007fea0d9d6a60:   0000000000000000 00007fea0d9d6ac8
0x00007fea0d9d6a70:   00000000b11bfb58 0000000000000000
0x00007fea0d9d6a80:   00000000b113c588 0000000000000000
0x00007fea0d9d6a90:   00007fea0d9d6ab8 00007fea0d9d6b10
0x00007fea0d9d6aa0:   00007fea01006175 00000000eadefc40
0x00007fea0d9d6ab0:   00007fea0100ecd7 0000000000000375
0x00007fea0d9d6ac0:   00007fea0479fbb0 0000000000000001
0x00007fea0d9d6ad0:   00007fea0d9d6ad0 00000000b113c661
0x00007fea0d9d6ae0:   00007fea0d9d6b48 00000000b11bfb58
0x00007fea0d9d6af0:   0000000000000000 00000000b113c6b0
0x00007fea0d9d6b00:   00007fea0d9d6ab8 00007fea0d9d6b38
0x00007fea0d9d6b10:   00007fea0d9d6b90 00007fea01006175
0x00007fea0d9d6b20:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fea0d9d6b30:   0000000000000000 0000000000000375
0x00007fea0d9d6b40:   00007fea0479fbb0 0000000000000000
0x00007fea0d9d6b50:   00007fea0d9d6b50 00000000b08f636b
0x00007fea0d9d6b60:   00007fea0d9d6bc0 00000000b1106b88
0x00007fea0d9d6b70:   0000000000000000 00000000b08f63f0
0x00007fea0d9d6b80:   00007fea0d9d6b38 00007fea0d9d6bb0
0x00007fea0d9d6b90:   00007fea0d9d6c08 00007fea01006233
0x00007fea0d9d6ba0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fea0d9d6bb0:   00007fea0479fbb0 00000000eb208878
0x00007fea0d9d6bc0:   00000000eae11880 00007fea0d9d6bc8
0x00007fea0d9d6bd0:   00000000b136de95 00007fea0d9d6c28
0x00007fea0d9d6be0:   00000000b13758d8 0000000000000000
0x00007fea0d9d6bf0:   00000000b136df18 00007fea0d9d6bb0
0x00007fea0d9d6c00:   00007fea0d9d6c28 00007fea0d9d6c70 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007fea00c91718)
0x00007fea00c916f8:   0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 55 53 48 89 fb 48 83 ec
0x00007fea00c91708:   08 48 85 ff 74 21 48 8b 07 89 f5 48 85 c0 74 06
0x00007fea00c91718:   48 83 38 50 74 3a be 50 00 00 00 48 89 df e8 05
0x00007fea00c91728:   86 01 00 85 c0 75 29 48 8d 15 30 1e 02 00 48 8d 

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000003e00 is an unknown value
RBX=0x00007fea0479fbb0 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000000375 is an unknown value
RDX=0x00007fea0479fbb0 is an unknown value
RSP=0x00007fea0d9d6a10 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fea0400a800
RBP=0x0000000000000375 is an unknown value
RSI=0x0000000000000375 is an unknown value
RDI=0x00007fea0479fbb0 is an unknown value
R8 =0x00000000ffffffff is an unallocated location in the heap
R9 =0x0000000000005300 is an unknown value
R10=0x00007fea01012d6c is at code_begin+620 in an Interpreter codelet
method entry point (kind = native)  [0x00007fea01012b00, 0x00007fea01013360]  2144 bytes
R11=0x00007fea0c821b80: <offset 0x8b3b80> in /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so at 0x00007fea0bf6e000
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x00000000b113c588 is an oop
{method} 
 - klass: {other class}
R14=0x00007fea0d9d6ac8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fea0400a800
R15=0x00007fea0400a800 is a thread


Stack: [0x00007fea0d8d9000,0x00007fea0d9da000],  sp=0x00007fea0d9d6a10,  free space=1014k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libgobject-2.0.so.0+0x19718]  g_object_get_qdata+0x18
```

Answer (score 0):

That's native code (gnome libraries used by eclipse), See
C  [libgobject-2.0.so.0+0x19718]  g_object_get_qdata+0x18

This info will be much more useful for Eclipse / Google guys. File them a bug. We the lowly users cannot tell what exactly was wrong at your side.